# #define as unsigned char

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know how can I tell to compiler that a `#define` is an `unsigned char`.
if `#define` 1 byte do this:

```
   #define AACEESS_PSS 0x80
    #define ACCESS_PSS  ((unsigned char)0x80)
```

but if `#define` has more byte what should to do??
for example:

```
 #define ACCESS_PSS {0x32,0xFD,0x6E,0x2D}
```

I need this cast for assign `#define` with `unsigned char`

```
int main(){
unsigned char ResponseData[100];
for (int i = 0; i <4;i++0){

                if (ResponseData[i+5]==ACCESS_PSS){ //how to do this???
                            cout<<5<<endl;
                                          }
```

`ResponseData` from programm get value and byte 5 to 8 is equal with `ACCESS_PSS`.

Comment: Do you think `{0x32,0xFD,0x6E,0x2D}` is of type `unsigned char`?

Comment: hint: Answer to @SouravGhosh is no. Can you specify the conceptual problem you are facing? As it stands this question will go nowhere.

Comment: #define is simply text replacement - how the compiler treats it will depend on how you use AACEESS_PSS in your code

Comment: It seems, [`girl71`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/184153/girl71) doesn't even have an account on SO yet.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca That's because the question has been migrated from programmers.se, where she has one.

Comment: FWIW, this is the second try from OP after failing the last attempt with the same queston here itself on day before yesterday, AFAIR. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> ResponseData[i+5]==ACCESS_PSS

You can't compare four `unsigned chars` with single equality operator in C.

You can convert to uint32_t, but it may break due to unaligned access or different endianness, i.e.:

```
#define ACCESS_PSS    0x32FD6E2D
...
if(*((uint32_t*) (ResponseData + i + 5)) == ACCESS_PSS) { /*...*/ }
```

The only **clean** way to do that is `memcmp`, or similiar function:

```
const unsigned char access_pss[4] = {0x32,0xFD,0x6E,0x2D};
...
if(memcmp(ResponseData + i + 5, access_pss, 4) == 0) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Sorry for being picky but with the clean solution `ACCESS_PSS` has to be lower case `access_pss`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this solution is Endianness-dependent.

Comment: @barakmanos: which solution? memcmp is not dependent, and I already noted that using uint32_t can be dangerous.

Comment: In addition, you might want to change that `[4]` to `[]`, and to change the other `4` to `sizeof(access_pss)/sizeof(*access_pss)`.

Comment: If the purpose is just byte-comparison then you are right, Endianness has no impact here.

Answer (score 0):

Since C99 we have compound literals for that:

```
#define ACCESS_PSS (unsigned char const[]){0x32,0xFD,0x6E,0x2D}
```

You can still use it as `ACCESS_PSS[2]` e.g.

The `const` in the definition allows the compiler to do optimisations, in particular it may avoid to have multiple copies of that array all over.